# Jetson Nano Not Detecting Grove Sensors Using Grove Base HAT

Tags: python, sensors, gpio, i2c, nvidia-jetson-nano

I recently got started trying to connect a [Grove PIR Motion Sensor](https://www.seeedstudio.com/Grove-PIR-Motion-Sensor.html) & [Grove NFC Reader](https://www.seeedstudio.com/Grove-NFC.html) to my Jetson Nano, using the [Grove Base HAT](https://www.seeedstudio.com/Grove-Base-Hat-for-Raspberry-Pi.html):

I followed these two guides to get the necessary libraries set up in order to interface with the Grove devices:

1. https://www.seeedstudio.com/blog/2019/04/19/instruction-on-how-to-use-nvidia-jetson-nano-with-grove/
2. https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/grove.py/

So, when I tried to test the PIR Motion Sensor, I encountered an issue. I first tried testing it using the test specified here on the sensor's [Wiki page](https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/Grove-PIR_Motion_Sensor/).

However, all that showed up when I tried this test was the following:

> Hat Name = 'Grove Base Hat RPi'

and then blank lines following.

Next I tried using the test in the aforementioned [GitHub page](https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/grove.py/blob/master/doc/README.md).

However, this time, all I got was an endless stream of

> Watching

indicating that it wasn't picking up the movement I was doing in front of it, or wasn't getting the input from the sensor.

Additionally, using `i2cdetect -r -y 1` with the sensor plugged in yields the following:

```
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- 04 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

Indicating the Grove Base HAT is being detected, but I don't know if this would also show if the sensor is connected.

So, I was wondering if someone might know what the issue is, either the sensor not working, or the Jetson Nano not being able to get the input from it, and how I might be able to resolve this issue.

Furthermore, none of the guides above mention anything about the NFC Reader, so I was wondering if anyone had any experience setting that up as well.